# Deploy Solr at the same port as tomcat

Tags: tomcat, solr, lucene, port

We have our web application hosted on the tomcat server on port 8080 (UNIX server).

https://example.com/myApp

We want to implement SOLR search in our project. SOLR suggests we should no more deploy SOLR as a web application. Please refer the link below.
https://wiki.apache.org/solr/WhyNoWar

Default SOLR installation (uses jetty, I think?) deploys it on any port we specify.

We don't want to open any ports other than 8080 on our server because most of the users we target have all the ports blocked except the default port.

Is there a way to host SOLR without deploying it in tomcat and still host it as? https://example.com/solr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best bet is to use proxy, for example nginx. Here is a sample how http block of nginx configuration may look for this case:

```
http {  
    upstream tomcat {
      server localhost:8081;
    }

    upstream solr {
      server localhost:8082;
    }

    server {
        listen       *:8080;
        server_name  my.server.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://tomcat;
        }

        location /solr/ {
            proxy_pass http://solr;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Solr` is still a web app. They are suggesting that not to use it in another servlet container as its not been recommended and tested by them.

They are giving a fully tested system and don't want others(developers) to invest time in testing it with other containers.

I have used `solr` 3.4 version and deployed it in tomcat server on port 8080. 
My application is deployed in another `tomcat` at 8080 port and is on another machine.

So there in not ambiguity about the port as both tomcats are on the different servers.

I have created the solr war and deployed the same in tomcat. and only 8080 port of that server is made open and been access by our application only.

I am not sure about the `solr` version 5 ...i.e. whether that can be deployed in other container other than `jetty`...but I think it can be deployed in `tomcat`...you need to try the same...

Other thing is that dont deply application war and `solr` war in the same container or in a single container. The reason is if one of the application goes down everything will be down.

Like if `solr` goes down then the application may go down, which is not a good for the application.